# Prevent QMainWindow from jumping to foreground after closing QDialog

Tags: qt, qmainwindow, qdialog

I'm developing a Qt-based app, using `QMainWindow` class for the GUI. This app has a built-in server that listens for requests from my Chrome Browser extension, so that I may import information from current web-page into my Qt-app.

So when I press extension's button in the browser, it sends a signal to my Qt-app, which then pops up a `QDialog` so that I can add some additional information like tags, etc. When I close the `QDialog`, I expect to return to the browser, but instead my app's main window pops up into foreground if it wasn't minimized (if it was minimized, then it doesn't pop up).

How can I change this behavior, so that I return to my browser after closing `QDialog`, no matter if the app's main window was minimized or not? If that helps, when creating `QDialog`, I pass 0 as parent to it.